# Definition of continuous function with $\delta-\epsilon$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The definition says: Let $(X,d_{1})$ and $(Y,d_{2})$ be a metric space. A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is called continuous if for every $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that:

$d_{1}(x,y)<\delta\Rightarrow d_{2}(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$

does it mean that $x,y\in X$ and $f(x),f(y)\in Y$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what that means.

Comment: @DMcMor ok, so the use of elements $x,y$ was confusing, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wording is a bit unclear but here's a rephrasing of the definition that may be a bit more clear:

> Fix $x\in X$. We say that $f:X\to Y$ is *continuous at $x$* if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that the following condition holds: if $y\in X$ such that $d_1(x,y)<\delta$, then $d_2(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$.
>
> We say $f$ is *continuous* if it is continuous at every $x\in X$.

If I've interpreted your question wrong, let me know and I can try to update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\;\;\;\;f $ is continuous at $X $
$$\iff $$

$(\forall x\in X )\;\;\;f $ is continuous at $x $
$$\iff $$
$$(\forall x\in X) \;\;(\forall \epsilon>0)\;\;(\exists \delta>0 )\;:\;\color {green}{(\forall y\in X )}$$
$$(d_1 (x,y)<\delta\implies d_2 (f (x),f (y))<\epsilon).$$

of course $f (x) $ and $f (y) $ are in $Y $ since $f :X\to Y $.